# Trouble exporting query to Excel from Access

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am attempting to export a query based on two combo boxes to excel.  Two weeks ago, this code worked.  I have moved the database, and updated the code.  Now, when I run it, it will open the query, and open excel, but it will NOT rewrite the excel file.  It just opens up the old data.

Access 2010

Code:

```
Private Sub Command14_Click()

DoCmd.OpenQuery "rtnbymonth_qry", acViewNormal, acEdit
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "rtnbymonth_qry", acFormatXLS, "S:\Sales & Use Tax\2016\export.xls"
DoCmd.Close acQuery, "rtnbymonth_qry", acSaveNo

'Open Excel
Call OpenSpecific_xlFile
End Sub
```

Also here is the code for the program to open excel:

```
'mini program to open excel

Sub OpenSpecific_xlFile()
 '   Late Binding (Needs no reference set)
Dim oXL As Object
Dim oExcel As Object
Dim sFullPath As String
Dim sPath As String


 '   Create a new Excel instance
Set oXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")


 '   Only XL 97 supports UserControl Property
On Error Resume Next
oXL.UserControl = True
On Error GoTo 0


 '   Full path of excel file to open
On Error GoTo ErrHandle
sFullPath = CurrentProject.Path & "\export.xls"


 '   Open it
With oXL
    .Visible = True
    .Workbooks.Open (sFullPath)
End With


ErrExit:
    Set oXL = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    oXL.Visible = False
    MsgBox Err.Description
    GoTo ErrExit
End Sub
```

Comment: First, you do not need to open or close the query to run [DoCmd.OutputTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192065.aspx). Second, this method uses an *AutoStart* argument to open file after it processes. Finally, if you receive no errors, output should have worked -check your `OpenSpecific_xlFile` subroutine. Maybe you are opening the previous file?

Comment: Possibly you have a permissions problem? Can you manually save an Excel file to that path? You can omit the first and third line ('.OpenQuery' and '.Close') and achieve the same result.

Comment: @parfait I can open the file without access, and there is no new data written to it.  I did not think that the open command would make a difference. Can you suggest how to trouble shoot? @ wayne G. Dunn I can edit and save the file that it is supposed to which is is support to overwrite.

Comment: I would either reboot the PC or open Task Manager to make sure no hidden copies of Excel are lurking about. Next, delete the 'Export.xls' file, then place a breakpoint on your line 'Call Open Specific...' and when the code halts, take a look at your Excel file. Let us know what you find...

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the location I was saving it to is different than the location where the database is stored.  The correct file was saved, just not in the location I was opening it.  Easy fix! Programmer error.

Comment: Exactly what I thought and commented! Again, you do not need the subroutine. Just use the *AutoStart* feature of `DoCmd.OutputTo`